# BottomSheet peek height not correct first time

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a RelativeLayout as a bottom sheet with com.android.support:design:25.1.0

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="true"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="100dp"
            >
```

The peekHeight is set to 100dp, when I'm opening the activity the bottomsheet is showing but with less than 100dp height. When expanding and collapsing it with the finger, the height of the bottom sheet is 100dp.

Why at the first opening the activity the peek height is not correct? Is it the normal behavior? I would like to have always the same height.

Comment: It seems it is due to the  android:layout_marginTop="56dp", how can I have a top margin without this issue?

Comment: Instead of using margin top why dont you use padding top?

Comment: Actually the padding will set a marge between the top of the bottom sheet and the content. But I want a margin from the top of the bottom sheet and the action bar when expanded...